# how to test move updates in variable listener

Tags: timefold

Is there anyway to test move updates in variable listener?
My problem is following:

1. I have an initial schedule problem, the problem is then solved (old solution)
2. I do a move, a new solution is created.
   How should I test this move?
   I already think of testing the solution score changes, but is there any better way to test it

Thanks in advance

Comment: For reference and in case you haven't figured out a way to achieve your goal: I've asked a somewhat related question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77946941/how-do-i-integration-test-custom-variable-listeners-to-ensure-no-score-corrupt/77947327#77947327 There might be some useful information for you

Comment: Thanks for your mentioning. It is good to know that there won't be a way to directly test the Move, at least until now